# How to integrate the Firebase Crashlytics function without Internet of my computer

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics

My current problem is that I can't connect to the Internet. I can't do it at one time, because the computer used by the company can only connect to the company's intranet in order to protect the code and data. The Internet is not open, so I still want to integrate the Firebase Crashlytics function when the computer is not connected to the Internet. Is there a way to download the dependent library first and then rely on the library locally? If so, can you give me specific implementation steps, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Firebase here and thanks for your question. In order to get the SDKs, you would need to have access from the project you're adding them to or another project that already has them locally.

After you downloaded and incorporated the SDKs, you would need to add the app via the Firebase console (Also, needs internet access, but you could set it up and then download the `google-services.json` file and copy it to your local project)

If you configured all of that, then you could use `gradle --offline` in order to prevent Gradle from trying to download all of the SDKs once again. However, even with all that, the SDKs need to connect to the internet in order to send the crash report.

In summary, you likely could get this to work, but it would be very prone to difficulty and error. I'm not sure why your company has such harsh restrictions on downloading SDKs.